# "Verifying DMI Pool" hang caused by raid array

Tags: centos, raid, boot

I have a problem, I obtained a new server with 4 hard drives (2 500 gig, 2 two TB), and an adeptec RAID card.

I arranged them in two arrays with RAID 1 (500 gigs together as primary and the 2 TB drives for lots of data).

When both arrays are configured, the server hangs while booting at message "Verifying DMI Pool", however if I remove the second array from the configuration the server boots fine.

I have checked they are both on different channels, I have disabled all other peripherals from the boot menu and ensured the hard drive is #1. I have booted into the linux rescue mode and checked that it is reading both arrays fine.

What else could be causing these problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, update motherboard BIOS and Adaptec firmware.

Comment: and if that doesn't work then I would?

Comment: Сontact tech support Adaptec.